# Type Error in filter function

Tags: react-native, react-android

I am trying to make a autocomplete text box in React Native. I am getting an error in filter function. When the user types the services then the text box should get autocompleted with the full name of the service.The service name is coming from my json file. I am using 'react-native-autocomplete-input' in order to accomplish this.   Below is the screen shot of the error:

[image]

Below is my App.js code.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */



import service from './services.json';


import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native';



class Autocomp extends Component {
  static renderServices(coservice) {
    const { ser, Location, secondLoc} = coservice;


    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>{ser}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.openingText}>{secondLoc}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       query: '',
       services:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      const {results: services} = service;
      this.setState({services});

  }




    findServices(query) {
      const inputValue = query.trim().toLowerCase();
      const inputLength = inputValue.length;

      const { services } = this.state;
      return inputLength === 0 ? [] : services.filter(ser =>ser.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue);
  }




  render() {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const services = this.findServices(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          data={services.length === 1 && comp(query, services[0].ser) ? [] : services}
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Enter Services here"
          renderItem={({ ser, Phone }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: ser })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {ser} 
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
        <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
          {services.length > 0 ? (
            Autocomp.renderServices(services[0])
          ) : (
            <Text style={styles.infoText}>
              Enter services
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 25
  },
  autocompleteContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    left: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 1
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    margin: 2
  },
  descriptionContainer: {
    // `backgroundColor` needs to be set otherwise the
    // autocomplete input will disappear on text input.
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    marginTop: 25
  },
  infoText: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  directorText: {
    color: 'grey',
    fontSize: 12,
    marginBottom: 10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  openingText: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
export default Autocomp;
```

Below is my services.json file

```
{
    "id":1,
    "ser": "Service1",
    "Location": "TestLoc1",
    "Phone":"(999)-921-9292",
    "SecondLoc": "TestLoc",
    "email":"accrmail@test.com",
    "sourceLat":"33.977806",
    "sourceLong":"-117.373261",
    "destLatL1":"33.613355",
    "destLongL1":"-114.596569",
    "destLatL2":"33.761693",
    "destLongL2":"-116.971169",
    "destAddr1": "Test Drive, 99999",
    "destAddr2": "Test City, Test Drive, 92345"
  },

  {
    "id":1,
    "ser": "TestService",
    "Location": "TestLoc1",
    "Phone":"(999)-921-9292",
    "SecondLoc": "TestLoc",
    "email":"accrmail@test.com",
    "sourceLat":"33.977806",
    "sourceLong":"-117.373261",
    "destLatL1":"33.613355",
    "destLongL1":"-114.596569",
    "destLatL2":"33.761693",
    "destLongL2":"-116.971169",
    "destAddr1": "Test Drive, 99999",
    "destAddr2": "Test City, Test Drive, 92345"
  },
  ]
```

any help will be highly appreciated. I checked the function. everything looks correct.

Comment: Can you add your `services.json` ?

Comment: sorry, forgot to do that. I just edited my post. Added services.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `json` file is as shown here, there are two problems with your code.

- Destructuring is wrong. Since you're directly importing an object from a `json` file as name `services`, *which has not been assigned to any named constant / variable*, therefore it cant be destructured.

Therefore you must change the code as

```
import services from './services.json';

componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({services});
  }
```

- You're trying to convert a **`service` object** `toLowerCase` here
  `ser =>ser.toLowerCase()` 
  which needs to be changed to

  ```
  services.filter(({ser}) => ser.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue);
  ```

Comment: Thank You Pritish. I am just taking classes of React Native online and developing the code at the same time so making mistakes. Thank you for all your help!